# How do you make daylight sensors turn to night mode and if it day turn to day time mode without touching the daylight sensors

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-education-edition

I've tried looking up the answers on google and nothings given me what Im trying to do. Im trying to make my daylight sensor turn to night mode if it's night and turn to day mode if it's the day. Im trying to make an automatic light detector so it turns on my lights if it's night and turns on my lights if it's the day so I don't have to be in the dark and so I don't have to do it by hand.

[image]

Comment: "turn on the lights if its day and turn them on if its night" so do you want them always on? Or just not for that small time window in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the state of a daylight sensor without right clicking on it or using command blocks.

If you want to keep the light always on you could use a redstone block or redstone torch, or you could use two daylight sensors with an OR gate if you want to turn off the lamp during the morning and evening.

Comment: I want it to be as small as possible though is there a way to make it smaller

Comment: @CameronJohnson AND gates can be fairly compact

Comment: How would you use the gate

Comment: @CameronJohnson Just realized I meant OR gate, not AND gate. Pretty much all you have to do is have the signal from two daylight sensors leading into one redstone line. If either daylight sensor is on then the line will turn on. If you need more help than that, look up some redstone tutorials or ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question